# Possible Rational Canonical Forms of a matrix in $M_{15}(\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to find all possible rational canonical forms of a matrix in $M_{15}(\mathbb{Q})$ given that its minimal polynomial is $m_A(x) = (x^2 + x + 1)^2(x^3 + 2)^2$.

I wanted to start by first finding the possible characteristic polynomials of which I found only one possibility $c_A(x) = (x^2+x+1)^3(x^3+2)^3$.

Now I know I have the following in my RCF: $C(x^2+x+1)^2 \oplus C(x^3+2)^2$

Now I need to add factors to bring it up to my characteristic poly which would mean adding $C(x^2+x+1) \oplus C(x^3+2)$, giving RCF = $C(x^2+x+1)^2 \oplus C(x^3+2)^2 \oplus C(x^2+x+1) \oplus C(x^3+2)$.

This doesn't seem right as I haven't used the fact that we are over the rationals. Is my characteristic poly wrong?

Comment: You've edited out the minimal polynomial, which was crucial information. I've edited it back in.

Comment: Note that $C(x^2+x+1)^2 \oplus C(x^3+2)^2$  is not the standard presentation of RCF; typically, we would use the block $C[(x^2+x+1)^2(x^3+2)^2]$ (which is equal up to isomorphism).

Comment: @BenGrossmann Cheers sorry about that

Comment: That earlier comment should say up to *similarity*, not isomorphism

Answer (score 1):

The RCF of a matrix is determined by the invariant factors of $A$. We know that these factors divide each other (i.e. $f_1 \mid \cdots \mid f_k$), the largest of these factors is the minimal polynomial, and the product of these factors is the characteristic polynomial.  With that said, we are looking for collections of polynomials $f_1,\dots,f_{k-1},f_k$ with $f_k = m_A$ such that $f_1 \mid \cdots \mid f_k$ and $f_1 \cdots f_k = c_A(x)$.

With that requirement, the only possibility is to take $f_1 = (x^2 + x + 1)(x^3 + 2)$ and $f_2 = m_A$. With that, we see that the corresponding RCF is
$$
C((x^2 + x + 1)(x^3 + 2)) \oplus C((x^2 + x + 1)^2 (x^3 + 2)^2).
$$